# How to get column data value in an array using Javascript (No .Net coding)

Tags: jquery

I am working on Sharepoint 2007 and I have a Sharepoint Document library having 3 columns namely : Type, Name, Modified BY. Column "Name" is having all the folders inside it. On clicking the folder, a Document or a sub folder inside it opens. I want to collect all the Folder name present in this "Name" column into a separate array. Only collecting Name will do. Can anyone help me in this. I can only use Javascript or Jquery to get the data into an array.

I tried using jquery by readin td's and tr's and finding the particular class for this column (ms-vb-icon) but not gettng any data into it. Please help me if anyone has done this earlier.

Best Regards